# Convert Unix time to readable DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, unix-timestamp

I would like to convert a Unix time stamp to readable DateTime.
when the value is 1423525935 i'm getting "January 17, 1970 01:25"  and not "Feb 09 2015 23:52:15"

Thnx

my script

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm ");
    String date1 = sdf.format(properties.get("time"));
    System.out.println(date1);
    System.out.println(properties.get("time"));
```

and my output is

```
1423525935
January 17, 1970 01:25 
1423525976
January 17, 1970 01:25 
1423526012
January 17, 1970 01:25 
1423526026
January 17, 1970 01:25 
1423526047
January 17, 1970 01:25 
1423526172
January 17, 1970 01:25
```

Comment: Elizion already gave the correct answer. As a side note, make sure you set the timezone of the SimpleDateFormat class. By default it will take the timezone of the server it's running on, which may be good enough for you if you never have your server running in a different timezone than the users of your application.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a seconds-based Unix Epoch value, whereas you require a time in milliseconds for your `SimpleDateFormat`. Thus, you must multiply your current `Long` values by 1000 in order to get the correct dates. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm ");
int time = Integer.parseInt(properties.get("time")); //if time property is not an int
Long l = time * 1000L;
String date1 = sdf.format(l);
System.out.println(date1);
```

This gives output of `February 9, 2015 05:52`.

As Elizion's answer mentioned you are using seconds based Epoch time, I converted into Milli seconds by multiplying 1000 to it.

Comment: thanks, but how do i insert the "time" parameter to parameter "l" ?

Comment: if your time parameter is in string format you can convert it to int first & then to long `Long l = Integer.parseInt(properties.get("time"))*1000L;`